# console.log() don't have result

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I'm doing API address then I write console.log() but when see in console it don't have result

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.province').change(function(){
    var select=$(this).val();
    console.log(select);
  });
</script>
```

```html
<select name="province" id="province" class="form-control province">
         <option value="">เลือกจังหวัด</option>
           @foreach($list as $row)
                 <option value="{{$row->id}}">{{$row->name_th}}</option>
             @endforeach
 </select>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!
`val()` is empty, by default `val()` index is 0 which is first number in array. You will get first `value` of options, `<option value="">เลือกจังหวัด</option>` this `value` is empty. that's why you don't get any result.

Answer (score 1):

If you are reffering a class you should use:
$(“.province”)
But in this case you want to reffer an ID instead, so you should use:
$(“#provice”)

Greetings.

Comment: I used it but don't have anythig too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this

```
<select name="province" id="province" onchange="functionName()" class="form-control province">
     <option value="">เลือกจังหวัด</option>
     @foreach($list as $row)
          <option value="{{$row->id}}">{{$row->name_th}}</option>
     @endforeach
</select>



<script type="text/javascript">

    function functionName(){
        var select = document.getElementById("province").value;
        console.log(select);
    }
</script>
```

Or You have to use like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#province').change(function(){
        var select=$(this).val();
        console.log(select);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: don't have result too

Comment: You have to first check `change` is working?? like `alert('Hello')` before `var select`

Answer (score 0):

What if you use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#province').on('change', function(){
            var select=$(this).val();
            console.log(select);
        });
    });
</script>
```